# How to delete the same string in python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I use python3.6
I want to delete the same string,and this is my code.

```
r = [['I1', 'I2'], ['I1', 'I3'], ['I1', 'I5'], ['I2', 'I3'], ['I2','I4'], ['I2', 'I5']]
for v in range(len(r)):
    for k in range(v+1,len(r)):
        union = list(set(r[v]) | set(r[k]))
        print(sorted(union))
```

and results is:

```
['I1', 'I2', 'I3']
['I1', 'I2', 'I5']
['I1', 'I2', 'I3']
['I1', 'I2', 'I4']
['I1', 'I2', 'I5']
['I1', 'I3', 'I5']
['I1', 'I2', 'I3']
['I1', 'I2', 'I3', 'I4']
['I1', 'I2', 'I3', 'I5']
['I1', 'I2', 'I3', 'I5']
['I1', 'I2', 'I4', 'I5']
['I1', 'I2', 'I5']
['I2', 'I3', 'I4']
['I2', 'I3', 'I5']
['I2', 'I4', 'I5']
```

how can I delete the same string?

Comment: Do you mean duplicate strings? Also, please clarify if you don't mean list of strings. You can show that by adding your expected output to your question.

Comment: @Kasrâmvd Thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created `Union_list` to keep track of what already got printed:

```
Union_list = [] 
r = [['I1', 'I2'], ['I1', 'I3'], ['I1', 'I5'], ['I2', 'I3'], ['I2','I4'], ['I2', 'I5']]
for v in range(len(r)):
    for k in range(v+1,len(r)):
        union = sorted(list(set(r[v]) | set(r[k])))
        if union not in Union_list:
            Union_list.append(union)
            print(union)
```

Output:

```
['I1', 'I2', 'I3']
['I1', 'I2', 'I5']
['I1', 'I2', 'I4']
['I1', 'I3', 'I5']
['I1', 'I2', 'I3', 'I4']
['I1', 'I2', 'I3', 'I5']
['I1', 'I2', 'I4', 'I5']
['I2', 'I3', 'I4']
['I2', 'I3', 'I5']
['I2', 'I4', 'I5']
```

Comment: @mad_ sure. Fixed it now :)